# how to show a column in a groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi stackoverflow community, i'm using this dataframe:

```
Client          Date     Amount 
Jack      10/01/2020        100
Jack      10/01/2020        200
Jack      10/01/2020        300
Jack      10/01/2020        400
Jack      12/01/2020        100
Jack      12/01/2020        100
Jack      13/01/2020        100
```

What i have noticed in pandas groupby that shows only the result without column name and i really want to have the column name to refere it in upcoming actions

***What i've tried ?***

```
result=df.groupby(["Client", "Date"])["Amount"].sum()
Client          Date     
Jack      10/01/2020        1000
Jack      12/01/2020        200
Jack      13/01/2020        100
```

***Desired Results***

```
 Client          Date         Amount
    Jack      10/01/2020        1000
    Jack      12/01/2020        200
    Jack      13/01/2020        100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
result=df.groupby(["Client", "Date"])["Amount"].sum().reset_index()
```